# Wpf DatagridComboBoxCell

Tags: .net, wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

How to create datagridComboBoxCell in Wpf so that runtime i can bind that cell??

Answer (score 0):

I guess u mean column not cell, don't you?

For a column you could use something like this:

```
<dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Current Category"

SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=CurrentCategory}"

  SelectedValuePath="CategoryID"

DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName"

ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoriesDataProvider}}">
```

If you want to change bindings at runtime u have to name your column and set the appropiate bindings in code.

I found the XAML solution in the [first result](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/12/17/wpf-datagrid-dynamically-updating-datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx) via google with search term "wpf datagrid combobox column".